# Correct way to express: no one is close

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

> *Are you sad, when no one's close?*

Is that question correct?

My question is about the part 'no one is close'. I mean 'when you are alone'. Or should I better say 'no one is close to you'.

Comment: Since 2017 this question has been bumped 16 times and has earned a miserly 78 views. Sometimes a post needs to be cremated: it's not useful, it's uninteresting, it's too easy, too trivial... At least that's what the 16 bumps and 78 views say.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the short snippet you provided, it's not totally clear what you mean by **close**. If you really mean "when you are alone," just say that:

> Are you sad when you are alone?

or

> Are you sad when you're all alone?

If you want to use close to mean physically close, I would use "close by":

> Are you sad when nobody is close by?

If you're talking more about emotional or familial closeness, I might say:

> Are you sad when nobody close to you is around?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's grammatically correct, but not quite common. I'd rather use "around" and not "close". Or you can alternatively say

> Are you sad, when there's no one around?

I also think "to you" is implied where you say "when no one's close".

Comment: It depends on what the OP is trying to say, though. You can have lots of people around you, yet still feel lonely and not close to anyone. “Close" can mean close in proximity, or close emotionally. If the OP is talking about the former, then your suggestion is excellent. If it’s the latter, though, then it might still need some work.

Comment: Yes @JR, you're right. Good point